# Swashbuckle Additional description for swagger dictionary response

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Is it possible to enhance the swagger output when you are using dictionary values as either the response or a property on the type?

I am using Swashbuckle Annotations with example SchemaFilter types

Dictionary as a response example

```
[SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "A dictionary containing the property validation errors", typeof(Dictionary<string, string>), contentTypes: "application/json")]
```

Dictionary as a property on a type example

```
public class TypeToReturn
{
    [SwaggerSchema(Description = "Dictionary<string, object>")]
    
    public IDictionary<string, object> PropertyValues { get; }
}
```

I can put a more descriptive string in the description field but I would like the outputted example to be better than below as for the property example, it is a dictionary of strings to objects and not strings to strings which the swagger assumes.

```
{
  "additionalProp1": "string",
  "additionalProp2": "string",
  "additionalProp3": "string"
}
```

I've read that you can use additionalProperties in the swagger definition but can't see a way to provide that information in Swashbuckle.